# Scala Map Option

Tags: json, scala, scala-collections, jackson-databind

I have a map in scala like this.

```
val someData = Some(Map(genderKey -> gender,agekey -> age))
```

How to get the output as:

```
 val key= genderkey 
 val value= gender
 val key2 =  agekey (Dynamic variable name)
 val value2= age (Dynamic variable name)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: val output = somdata.mapValues(x => if (x.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]) Some(x) else x)
 val valueToField = output("fieldname").asInstanceOf[Option[Map[String, String]]].get. Here after i don't have much idea make it as dynamic

Comment: Does Simon's answer work for you? (`someData.map(_.map( case (k, v) => s"val $k = $v"))`)

Comment: I tried but not working as I need it in dynamic manner

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? I don’t understand what you mean by “in dynamic manner”. What is “dynamic” about it?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
someData.map(_.map { 
    case (k,v) => s"$k = $v" 
}
.mkString(" and \n"))
.foreach(result => println(result))
```